# Is selecting a subset of vectors a measure theory problem?

Tags: measure-theory, vector-fields, integer-programming, outer-measure

I have some vectors $\bf v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$. The goal is to select a subset of these vectors based on some criteria. Let's consider each of those vectors are some kind of investment and my problem is to find the best portfolio e.g. a selection $\left\{3,10,25\right\}$ corresponding to $\bf \left\{v_3, v_{10}, v_{25}\right\}$. I like to develop a measure over such selections (aka. subsets) let say $\mu\Big(\left\{3,10,25\right\}\Big)$.

There is a correspondence between the index sets, $\left\{1,2,\dots,n\right\}$ and the pre-defined vectors. I'm new to measure theory and I want to consider this as my toy example. Is there a particular setup from here? The finite countable set $\left\{1,2,\dots,n\right\}$ and its $\sigma$-algebra as powerset over this set seems well defined. But I'm not sure if it would be possible to take care of the correspondence between only indexes and the vectors which I try to design measure $\mu$.

The measure $\mu: E \to [0, \infty]$ which $E$ is a particular subset of $\left\{1,2,\dots,n\right\}$ e.g. $\left\{3,10,25\right\}$.

One trivial measure is the counting measure for this but I define the measure $\mu$ by taking into account the content of vector space V which my vectors are comes from. The vectors are fixed but the whole space is meaningful. What I'm not sure if such correspondence (having using $\bf v_i$ when measure the selection contains $i$) be suitable in realm of measure theory? Is there a particular topic which take care of such scenarios?

Comment: The measure $\mu$ should be scalar-valued (real or complex), but you are working with vectors, so it seems that you need a function that maps collections of vectors to scalars, e.g.. $\{3,10,25\} \mapsto \{v_3, v_{10}, v_{25}\} \mapsto f(v_3) + f(v_{10}) + f(v_{25})$, where $f$ maps vectors to numbers (some sort of price function, for example).

Comment: The measure is indeed $\mu: E \to [0,\infty]$ which $E$ denotes the indexes 1 to n. However, I want measure the selections i.e. ${1,2,5}$ versus ${3,6}$. The selection length can be arbitrary. The map from $\left\{v_1,v_2\right\}$ to (from) $\left\{1,2\right\}$ is trivial as it only take the indexes.

Comment: @Bungo, First let take the direction you have described above. It's OK to measure the singletons. Is my setup proper for a measurable space? What if just define it over the vectors then? My problem is the vector when realized from the vector space they are all fixed. I am not interested in manipulations of those vectors. I just want to find the best subset.

Comment: (Updated comment to reflect what I think is consistent with your notation.) If $2^X$ is the power set of $X=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$, then you can define $\mu$ on the singleton subsets of $X$, i.e. $\mu(\{1\}), \mu(\{2\}), \ldots, \mu(\{n\})$. Then that uniquely extends to a definition of $\mu$ on all of $2^X$ by $\mu(E) = \sum_{i \in E}\mu(\{i\})$ for every $E \subseteq X$.

Comment: It seems like the vectors themselves are irrelevant for your definition of $\mu$ - you can either define $\mu$ on the power set of $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ or on the power set of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and you'll get effectively the same measure (this is assuming that the $v_i$'s are all distinct, i.e. no repeats in the list).

Comment: @Bungo, right they all distinct and there is no repeat. However, my problem to lie this into measure theory problem is when I want to design $\mu$ to something other than trivial counting measure, I need the content of $v_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to measure it. This make it a bit ambiguous for me.

Comment: As long as you have some mapping in mind from $v_i$ to a nonnegative real number, for example $p_i$ = the price of whatever $v_i$ represents, then you can simply define $\mu(\{v_i\}) = p_i$, and that gives you a well-defined measure on all of $2^X$ assuming you extend it so it is additive, i.e. if $E$ is a set of some of the $v_i$'s, then $\mu(E)$ must be defined as the sum of the singleton measures $\mu(\{v_i\})$ of the $v_i$'s in $E$.

Comment: @Bungo, Thanks. Would you please make it an answer for me to make it approved? Also I'm thinking about the case that it might not be singleton measures independents I mean I might need to define a measure that changes the value based on other selections. Is this still proper measure? or an "outer measure"? Or I need to go with different models?